# Hook multichar (word) input in Android

Tags: android, events, keyboard

Using Google soft keyboard on Android I can catch keypress events and keydown events for individual characters; but when a word (e.g. 'pumpkin') is entered neither of these is triggered and so far I can't find any way to detect that word.

Does anyone know what event I need to watch / method to override in the view in order to catch words entered in the soft keyboard?